# Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/xml/strings.xml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, dart

I started studying Flutter and everything should work, yet it doesn't read xml file
Here's pubspec.yaml part :

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/xml/strings.xml
```

here's the part where xml should be read :

```
  void main(){
    String file = "";
    switch (type){
      case TYPE_STRING:
        file = 'assets/xml/strings.xml';
        break;
    }
    readFileAsync(file);
  }

  void readFileAsync(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Future<String> futureContent = file.readAsString();
    futureContent.then((xmlString) => {
      parseXml(xmlString)
    });
  }
```

And the error I get is

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/xml/strings.xml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Here how my assets are set in the project structure :
[image]

So, it seems to me I set up everything right, what's the problem?

Comment: Relative path require that the current working directory is set as you expect it to.  It rarely is unless you explicitly ask for .it.  Try printing out `file.getAbsolutePath()` and see where Java looks at the moment.

Comment: use `rootBundle` - this is how you should access your `assets` folder - the docs say: *"The AssetBundle from which this application was loaded.

The rootBundle contains the resources that were packaged with the application when it was built. To add resources to the rootBundle for your application, add them to the assets subsection of the flutter section of your application's pubspec.yaml manifest."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `rootBundle` to access resources from application package.

And also call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first, if you want to use `rootBundle` before `runApp` function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  String file = "";
  switch (type) {
    case TYPE_STRING:
      file = 'assets/xml/strings.xml';
      break;
  }
  readFileAsync(file);
}

Future<dynamic> readFileAsync(String filePath) async {
  String xmlString =  await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
  print(xmlString);
  return parseXml(xmlString);
}
```

Comment: u saved my life  <3

Comment: Not Ideal because rootBundle.loadstring is async and does not return a String