# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/image/download.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

Tags: flutter

I to run the zxing package example and i get this error.
Below is my example code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:zxing2/qrcode.dart';

getQRtext() {
  var image = img.decodePng(File('assets/image/download.png').readAsBytesSync())!;

  LuminanceSource source = RGBLuminanceSource(image.width, image.height,
      image.getBytes(format: img.Format.abgr).buffer.asInt32List());
  var bitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source));

  var reader = QRCodeReader();
  var result = reader.decode(bitmap);
  return result.text;
}
```

[image]

and this my image store file.
can anyone share me the solution. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/xml/strings.xml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436996/unhandled-exception-filesystemexception-cannot-open-file-path-assets-xml-s)

Comment: it not work for me. But is ok. Thanks a lot of ur sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want bytedata from asset image file,
you can use 'rootBundle'.

You need to confirm whether assets/image folder is added in pubspec.yaml.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image/download.png');
```